# Setting todays date as object property

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to set a property within one of my classes to the current date using PHP's built in date function.

```
class SomeClass {

public $var1;
public $var2;
public $todays_date = date("Y-m-d", time());

}
```

I keep getting an error message for this though: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in....

I can echo the date out using this function/format so I know that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can't use a function's return value as a default value of a property.

```
class SomeClass {

    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $todays_date;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->todays_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you cannot set the variable where you name it (in other words, you cannot initialize it on declaration).
You can set it in the constructor, e.g.

```
public $todays_date;

function __construct()
{
  $this->todays_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
}
```